# "Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist" in Android Studio in 2024 on Mac

Tags: android-studio

Using android studio for university assignment.

Received above error when using android studio on M1 MacBook. Works on windows pc.

Tried steps such as cleaning, rebuilding, invalidating cache\ restart, and uninstalling the app.

Any help would be much appreciated.